# TFS Map Team Projects to different folders

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm using the TFS Server offered by Visual Studio Online and Visual Studio 2013.
I've mapped the DefaultCollection to `C:\Users\xy\Source\TFS` and the first Team Project `TP1` to `C:\Users\xy\Source\TFS\TP1`.

Now I have a second Team Project `TP2` which would automatically be mapped to `C:\Users\xy\Source\TFS\TP2`. Is it possible to change the path for `TP2` to a completely different folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but not really straight-forward. I'd advise to have a clean workspace without any pending changes, especially in the team project that you want to map differently.

1. Open **Source Control Explorer**.
2. In the toolbar of the window you can see a drop down box with your workspace. Choose **Workspaces...**.
3. Select your workspace and click **Edit...**.
4. The dialog contains a grid **Working folders** that you can use to add special mappings. A picker dialog for the TFS side and the local file system structure support you in this task.
5. Leave all the dialogs with **Ok**.